# Android, Why Can't I Read the File I Just Wrote?

Tags: android

I am using the first snippet to write a file.

```
  String fileName = "Test6.txt";
    String outputString="Text for File";
    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(outputString.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the second to read it.

```
                    try{
                    FileInputStream InputStream = openFileInput("Text6.txt");
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(InputStream);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                    String lineData = bufferedReader.readLine();

                }catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, ex.getMessage());
                } 
                catch(IOException ex) {
                    Log.d(TAG, ex.getMessage());
                }
```

But I can't read it, I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.android.buildingmarque2/files/Text6.txt (No such file or directory)
```

I can also get a list of the files and Test6.txt is in the list.

Also, Android Studio Device File Explorer shows it.
[image: DeviceExplorer]

It could be a problem with the path.
Device Explorer, "Copy Path" gives me

/data/data/com.example.android.buildingmarque2/files/Test6.txt
But the Log says:

/data/user/0/com.example.android.buildingmarque2/files/Text6.txt

I'm confused?

Answer (score 1):

Typo.  One is "Text6" the other is "Test6".  Use a constant for both names to avoid this in the future

Comment: You have got to be kidding.  Where is the dunce cap?  Thanks